intellij # lines show in commit log
I'm trying to commit in IntelliJ. I'm using WSL2 Ubuntu and have set a commit template with:
git config commit.template $HOME/.gitmessage.txt.

When I commit in zsh, it works fine, but when I use the commit message box in IntelliJ, lines starting with # show up in the git log.
For example:
// .gitmessage.txt.
# something
this is commit msg
# commit body
## bla bla

Each git logs shows like this:
// using zsh
commit fadsfa441411ffafdaafd(HEAD -> main, origin/main, origin/HEAD)
Author: author <author@gmail.com>
Date:   Wed Jun 12 18:38:53 2024 +0900

    this is commit msg

// using intellij
commit fadsfa441411ffafdaafd(HEAD -> main, origin/main, origin/HEAD)
Author: author <author@gmail.com>
Date:   Wed Jun 12 18:38:53 2024 +0900

    # something
    this is commit msg
    # commit body
    ## bla bla

I want to get zsh result in IntelliJ. How can I fix this?
Installing the "Commit Message Template" plugin didn't work. Setting something in .git/hooks/... didn't work either.

Hi, this seems related to: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IJPL-72548/git-config-commit.template-not-work-by-absolute-path-in-WSL-repo
Can you try the EAP?

Thank you for your help.
I updated IntelliJ to the latest version, but the issue still persists. I also checked the link you mentioned. My main problem is that when I include # in the commit message(using intellij, committing in zsh works fine), it appears incorrectly in the commit log. Could you provide further assistance?

Can you share some screenshots

Exact commit message you have in UI
Output in the console tab (which appear in git log)
Resulting commit in log

